# Recommendation for learning math

Tags: reference-request, education, advice

I'm in the 11th grade. At the bachelor exam, my main focus will be on mathematics and informatics.

I'm a hard working man, but due to the school norms, I can consider myself idiot at math.
Why? Because the math that's studied at school is rubbish. It makes you reproduce, and not think. I'm also tutored at math, but with the same results.

I want to go on the same way I went with informatics, and this is by learning in private, alone.

Could you recommend me some books that can help me understand the whole high-school curriculum? A book/books that takes me from the very below (9th grade) till 12th grade?

Comment: The first and most basic skill in math, and pretty much any other human endeavour, is to be able to reproduce. From the very beginning, reproducing addition of digits (which are just memorized), reproducing the algorithms in arithmetics with decimal notation, to the most advanced works in mathematics, in which what their creators do is nothing else than reproducing ideas they have seen before but putting them together in new ways. I think then, that if your school has erred in some way, it is not in teaching you to reproduce, it is in motivating you.

Comment: I have noticed that one of the biggest stumbling blocks faced by struggling high school students is a lack of mastery of basic arithmetic -- e.g. the multiplication tables and fractions. "Strategies" for multiplication (grouping, finger math, shortcuts etc.) for "figuring out" 9x7 are all the rage in schools now. Unless you can instantly recognize from memorized multiplication tables that 28 and 42 have a common factor of 7, however, even the most basic algebra is next to impossible.

Comment: Good for you! Self learning is helpful in so many ways :) Are you assuming that 12th grade is pre-calc, or calculus? I would look through the Dover series of books. They are sometimes dated, but very cheap and often written by major workers in the field.

Comment: Re: Duplicate Status. The OP here seems to be working at an entirely different level from that at "Books for a beginner." You might want to reconsider.

Comment: Maybe I haven't explained the school problem correctly. The school shows you how to solve the problem just in a one way. If you try to elaborate a new solution and it's valid, the teachers don't considerate you, and they don't even try to help you. Their answer: "It's incorrect. It's not the way we are solving". These things motivates you to learn alone.

Comment: @RobertEagle Just reading a bit between the lines, but I know that school teachers like you to show your work in a way that is easily decipherable to them. It helps identify for both of you where you might have gone wrong on a question. It also makes it possible to assign part marks on exams. Even while you are studying on your own, it's probably better to follow the steps as outlined in your textbook. You may have to shop around for the best textbook for your particular learning style. Check out your public library. They usually have a selection of textbooks for each year of high school.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These books by Gelfand - an outstanding mathematician - who also wanted math taught correctly are excelent:

Algebra

[http://www.amazon.com/Algebra-Israel-M-Gelfand/dp/0817636773/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1383230077&sr=1-1&keywords=israel+gelfand](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0817636773)

and Trig

[http://www.amazon.com/Trigonometry-I-M-Gelfand/dp/0817639144/ref=pd_bxgy_b_img_y](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0817639144)

similarly for geometry by Kiselev

[http://www.amazon.com/Kiselevs-Geometry-Book-I-Planimetry/dp/0977985202/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1383230284&sr=1-1&keywords=Kiselev%27s+Geometry%3A+Book+1%2C+Planimetry](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0977985202)

These are all very math oriented, along the lines of what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I hope these websites help, they include everything from Mock Exam Papers to some PDF revision books etc. they're all 100% free and should help. Just pick your subject and what you're doing like for example GCSE, A Level (it might be different in America but it should have what you're looking for on the first website anyway). There's also worksheets and the second weblink has Edexcel Maths Activities for you practise.

http://www.freeexampapers.com/#/GCSE

http://pastebin.com/0NbYFzk5